# Setting a PM Time in CloudKit Dasboard

Tags: cloudkit

I am using the new CloudKit Dashboard to add to my public database. I can't seem to set a time that is PM anymore.

I am trying to enter a date 9/1/2017 8 pm and it always converts it to 8 AM.

I've tried:

```
09/01/2017 20:00:00
9/1/17 20:00:00
09/01/2017 08:00 PM
9/1/17 08:00 PM
09/01/2017 08:00 PM
```

Every single time when I hit save it changes the display time to:

```
9/1/2017 8:00:00
```

Which is 12 hours off. I thought maybe it was just a display issue but it's calculating in my app as 8am as well.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? It used to work to use military time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue with the new dashboard. I reached out to Apple Developer support yesterday, via email, and described what was happening.

We've only had our first email volley, so I haven't heard back about them closing (officially) the ticket, but I'm happy to report the date/time field appears to be fixed, I'm able to enter pm times without the value changing on save. Try it.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be fixed now. I had submitted a bug report when I posted this but they said it was a dupe and no timeline on when it would be fixed.